# How does the expression `echo echo ${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/} ` work to give me my home directory?

Tags: command-line, scripts, xdg, xdg-base-directory

`echo ${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/}` gives me the same result as `echo $HOME`.

Yet `$XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME` and `XDG_DATA_HOME` are not in my environment. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how these expressions are working. I know the basics of XDG.

```
> env | grep XDG               
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for can be found here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: Good redirection to duplicate. Thanks. I need to point out that these expressions are extremely hard to find using google search. So perhaps this kind of duplicate has a function as a search anchor.